# "TypeError: $(...) is null" error while showing bt tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display bt tooltip on button click. Here is my button:

```
<input type='button' name='ajay' id='ajay' value='ajay' onclick="test()"/>
```

Here is my jQuery/javascript code -

```
function test() {
    $('#ajay').bt('Contents of the tip is provided in the .bt() call',
        {
            trigger: 'click',
            positions: 'top'
        }
    );
    $('#ajay').btOn();
}
```

I am getting following error - `TypeError: $(...) is null`

Comment: Presumably you're including the jquery source above your code.

Comment: Why use the onclick attribute if you're using jquery?

Comment: You must include jquery library and tooltip library before calling this function

Comment: Try wrapping your code inside `$j(document).ready(function ()` to make sure your DOM is loaded

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines:

```
console.log("jQuery defined: " + $ === undefined)
```

It sounds like jQuery library isn't loading.